# Return anonymous from Func<T> as parameter in .Select()

Tags: c#, linq, generics, c#-3.0, anonymous-types

For the sake of "post processing" on a method, I want to import an extra function into a method.

**How can I import a `Func` that returns an anonymous Type as a parameter for a .Select extension method?**

The expression is anounymous like:

```
p => new
{
    ThumnailUrl = p.PicasaEntry.Media.Thumbnails[0].Attributes["url"],
    ImageUrl = p.PhotoUri
}
```

and needs to be used at parameter ????? and performed at .Select(?????)

```
private void BindControl<T, U>(string uri, DataBoundControl target, ?????)
    where T : KindQuery, new()
    where U : PicasaEntity, new()
{
    PicasaFeed feed = CreateFeed<T>(uri);
    albumList.DataSource = GetPicasaEntries<U>(feed).Select(?????);
    albumList.DataBind();
}
```

**update:**

finally I want to call it like:

```
    string albumUri = PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(PicasaUserID, PicasaAlbumID);
    BindControls<AlbumQuery, Album>(albumUri, albumList, ?????);

    string photoUri = PicasaQuery.CreatePicasaUri(PicasaUserID, PicasaAlbumID);
    BindControls<PhotoQuery, Photo>(photoUri, slideShow, ?????);
```

the other methods are like:

```
private PicasaFeed CreateFeed<T>(string uri) 
   where T : KindQuery, new()
{
    PicasaFeed feed = null;

    try
    {
        PicasaService service = new PicasaService(PicasaApplicationName);
        T query = new T();
        query.BaseAddress = uri;
        feed = service.Query(query);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //exception handling not shown
    }

    return feed;
}



private IEnumerable<T> GetPicasaEntries<T>(PicasaFeed feed) 
     where T : PicasaEntity, new()
{
    if(feed == null){
        return null;
    }

    IEnumerable<T> entries = null;
    string cacheKey = feed.Id.ToString();

    if(Cache.Get(cacheKey) == null)
    {
        entries = feed.Entries.Select(x => new T() { AtomEntry = x }).ToList();
    Cache.Insert(cacheKey, entries, 
              null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(0,20,0));
    }

    return entries;
}
```

Comment: What type parameter does your Select API take? It might be easiest to pass one of those in. Otherwise I'd expect you'd need to define your own named type with the two Url properties - I can't see why that wouldn't work instead.

Comment: Have you written GetPicasaEntries ? If so, it would be interresting to see this function signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types are really only designed for local use. In a strongly typed language types that can't be strongly typed are not really encouraged for general use... They are just a part of c#s little dance in the dynamic world.

You have two choices.

Create a strong type.

```
  class Entry
  {
    public string ThumnailUrl { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
  }
```

And then use :

```
  p => new Entry 
  {
     ThumnailUrl = p.PicasaEntry.Media.Thumbnails[0].Attributes["url"],
     ImageUrl = p.PhotoUri
  }
```

Or refer to it as Object. Then use reflection to get the data out - I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 2):

Could you add another generic parameter to `BindControl`? For example:

```
private void BindControl<T, U, V>(string uri, DataBoundControl target,
                                  Func<U, V> selector)
```

**Update**

Following your update, I'd suggest not to use generics in this way. You may be able to get it working via `BindControl<AlbumQuery, Album, Func<Album, dynamic>>`, but I would suggest that you pass query objects directly, making use of polymorphism, instead of using generics in this way.

Comment: You don't declare V - the compiler infers it to be your anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this, not sure whether it will work?

```
private void BindControl<T, U, V>(string uri, DataBoundControl target, Func<U,V> selector)
    where T : KindQuery, new()
    where U : PicasaEntity, new()
{
    PicasaFeed feed = CreateFeed<T>(uri);
    albumList.DataSource = GetPicasaEntries<U>(feed).Select(selector);
    albumList.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the MSDN documentation for select:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx

According to that the format is:

```
Func<TSource, TResult> selector
```

In your case the TResult would be your U parameter I belive.

UPDATE:
Why do you need to have a anonymous type. Is it not enough to be able to send in the predicate expression in the form of a func?

```
private void BindControl<T, U>(string uri, DataBoundControl target, Func<U, bool> selector)
        where T : KindQuery, new()
        where U : PicasaEntity, new()
    {
        PicasaFeed feed = CreateFeed<T>(uri);
        var feeds = GetPicasaEntries<U>(feed).Select(U);

    }

BindControl<AlbumQuery,Album>(albumUri,albumList,p=>p.Title=="Some title");
```

Comment: Not precisely. He clearly says that he is returning an anonymous type, which does not fit the restrictions on the generic types in the declaration of the `BindControl` method.

Comment: @Hosam Aly Yes I understand that, I'm only questioning if anonymous type is the way to go.